# How to rectify the error while processing GFA tool?

Tags: qgis-plugins

We are civil engineering students from India. As part of our final year B.tech project based on preparing Floodplain Map , we use QGIS. The tool we came across was GFA (Geomorphic Flood Area) tool. But while running the tool using the required inputs, an error cropped up showing :

```
"Starting...
Opening F:/DEM.tif
Opening F:/DEM.tif
Opening F:/drainagedirection3419.tif
Opening F:/flow accumulation3419.tif
Opening C:/Users/hp/Desktop/project qgis/New folder/Capture.tif
Error : Input files have different cell size "
```

We checked the pixel sizes of all the input files but all were the same. Can you help us to identify and rectify the error?